# iPad development tools that run on Windows?

Tags: windows, ipad

I've done a lot of looking around and have not found what I'm looking for. Does anyone know of dev tools for the iPad (and iPhone) that run on Windows?  I want to explore iPad application writing but do not want to buy a Mac quite yet.

I searched for related questions but didn't find anything, so apologies in advance if I blew that search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS development (both iPad and iPhone) is only available on OS X and Intel-based Mac computers.

Comment: You could try a hackintosh: http://www.hackintosh.com/ and http://www.insanelymac.com/  I would do this for sure if I couldn't afford one, but you didnt' hear it from me ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of tools that deploy to iOs devices. Most are focused on game development, such as Unity3D. [Marmalade](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com) seems to cover games and apps, and allows deploying to Android and iOs.

Please note that I didn't use it yet - I was looking for Windows tools and found this old question.

Answer (score 0):

Read this : http://aikhan.wordpress.com/2009/06/01/developing-iphone-applications-on-linux/

with some modifications toolchain can also be installed on windows.

It does not offer the tools that Apple provides to make development easier & reliable but it will get you started.

And you can always install GNUStep on your machine either on windows or linux to get a taste of objective C & Cocoa.

GNUStep is by the way open source implementation of cocoa.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious -- and currently free -- answer is to use Adobe FlashBuilder to develop iOS apps.  There is an iPhone and iPad emulator included.  This does not use xcode, but you get most of the features to work with, and you can also develop Android apps from the same set of code.

Adobe's website has [detailed directions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/index.html) for how to create iOS apps on Windows with Adobe Air, though the most useful instructions for Air are [from untoldentertainment.com](http://www.untoldentertainment.com/blog/2011/11/23/flash-to-ios-a-step-by-step-tutorial-part-1/).